# How to exclude hidden file ".htaccess" in rsync?

Tags: rsync

I want to exclude one special hidden file in just one special folder.

The command I used is:

```
rsync -a --delete                                 \
  --exclude='/absolute/path/to/webpage/folder1'   \
  --exclude='/absolute/path/to/webpage/backups'   \
  --exclude='/absolute/path/to/webpage/.htaccess' \
  /absolute/path/to/webpage/                      \
  /absolute/path/to/copy_of_webpage &>/dev/null
```

rsync always overwrites my `.htaccess`.

Also I want to keep my `.htpasswd` and I thought about using wildcards like:

```
rsync -a --delete                               \
  --exclude='/absolute/path/to/webpage/folder1' \
  --exclude='/absolute/path/to/webpage/backups' \
  --exclude='/absolute/path/to/webpage/.ht*'    \
  /absolute/path/to/webpage/                    \
  /absolute/path/to/copy_of_webpage &>/dev/null
```

But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude all `.htaccess` with `--exclude '.htaccess'`

Comment: Thanks. I actually need to exclude htaccess file for a special folder. Other htaccess files in other subfolders should be copied.

Comment: Then you'll have to specify it.

Comment: Thanks, but how? Can you give a special example in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the path *relative* to the source folder, not the absolute path.

If your root (as above) is:

```
/absolute/path/to/webpage/
```

and you wish to exclude:

```
/absolute/path/to/webpage/.htaccess
/absolute/path/to/webpage/backups
```

then you'll need to say:

```
--exclude='/.htaccess' --exclude='/backups'
```

Per the [docs](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html):

> `"/foo"` would match a file called `"foo"` at... the "root of the transfer"